# Angular data binding update on push to array WITHOUT cloning or using observables

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I have a "simple" question. Suppose I have an Angular component that in its class has a field which is an array. Suppose furthermore that in the component's template there is a data binding to this array (for example, because it's used in a ngFor directive). Is there any way to make Angular "re-evaluate" the data binding manually after due to some event push() (or another mutating method) is called on the array **without cloning and reassigning it or using a workaround with an Observable**?

I know this subject has been touched upon multiple times on this site, but I wonder if there is something I am missing since the usually suggested ways of making the data binding update are rather ugly in my opinion.

Thanks very much in advance,
Joshua

Comment: Can you provide what you already tried? Some sample at stackblitz maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm new to Angular and I have a "simple" question

It's not a simple question. This might be why you are reluctant to use one of the solutions you mentioned in bold. It is a complicated topic that relates to data mutation and how Angular handles change detection.

The short summary is that this is a **JavaScript** problem. Angular can not tell if an array has mutated by using a `===` operator, which is the bases for change detection in most frameworks like Angular, Rect and Vue.

> Is there any way to make Angular "re-evaluate" the data binding manually after due to some event push()

**No**

The problem is that when you call `push()` on an Array, the `old === new` values are both equal. Angular can not tell that the variable reference to the Array has changed. From Angular perspective the old and new values are identical.

This problem also exists for properties on an object. If you have a binding that uses an object reference, and you mutate a property. Angular will not know that the object has changed, and will not trigger change events on that binding.

> without cloning and reassigning it or using a workaround with an Observable

Those are the easiest ways. Anything else is more complicate and later when you come back to your source code you will wonder why you did it another way.

I can illustrate the problem with this code example;

```
 var a = [];
 var b = a;
 console.log(a === b); // prints true
 a.push({});
 console.log(a === b); // prints true
```

The code mutated the value of `a` but we want change detection to know that `a` is no longer the same as `b`. Since we get `true` twice then Angular will ignore the second *true* change test.

We can solve this problem by using `slice()`

```
 var a = [];
 var b = a;
 console.log(a === b); // prints true
 a = a.slice();
 a.push({});
 console.log(a === b); // prints false
```

Now the second *test* triggers *false* and Angular will know that the values have changed, and change detection will work for the components and directives (i.e. ngFor).

So when you need to *push()* values to an Array make sure to *slice()* it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  ngOnChanges(). A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes. Define an ngOnChanges() method to handle the changes.

for more check this [Doc](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to "re-evaluate" the data binding manually when you push an item, it might be automatic, however if you share your code we can have a better picture.

Thanks.
Andrea